# Preventing call forwarding popup on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

The following code sends a call forwarding command via intent

```
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intentCallForward.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "*21*001234567890#", "#");
intentCallForward.setData(uri);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```

The issue with this code is that it shows a popup which is a bit weird, is there a way to prevent this? Maybe via NDK or something like that?

Thanks in advance

[image: Call Forwarding Popup]

Answer (score 0):

The intent invokes the phone's phone activity. It is the source of your pop-up.

That is why you cannot change it or disable it.

If it really bothers you, you can include in your app some other calling activity and perform the call internally (not via intent), but I'm not sure such thing even possible, and it is surely doesn't worth the effort.